# How to have legend for multiple stat_function

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization, legend

I am creating the following graphs

```
data <- runif(100, 15, 45)
df <- data.frame(data)

graph_parameter_product <- function(data_set, column_value, bin_width, title_value) {
    graph <- ggplot(data_set, aes(x= column_value )) +
      geom_histogram(binwidth = bin_width, fill= "lightblue", colour= "black", aes(y=..density..)) + 
      xlab("Measurement") +
      ylab("Density") +
      labs(title = title_value ) +
      theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
      stat_function(fun = dnorm,
                    args = list(mean = mean(column_value), sd = sd(column_value)),
                    colour = "red", aes(colour = "Normal")) +
      stat_function(fun = dlnorm,
                    args = list(meanlog = mean(log(column_value)), sdlog = sd(log(column_value))),
                    colour = "black",  linetype="dotted", size=1.2, aes(colour = "LogNormal")) +
      scale_colour_manual("Distribution", values = c("red", "black"))
    
    graph 
  }
  
graph_parameter_product(df, data, 1, "Test Data")
```

**Quesstion1:**
I want to include legends in my graph. I believe I am doing everything correctly, but I'm still not getting the legend to appear. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Bonus question:**
I would prefer the y-axis to display the actual frequency instead of the density, but I couldn't find a way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

If you take the `color` specifications out of `state_fun` and leave them in the the aesthetics, it should work.

```r
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(2601)
data <- runif(100, 15, 45)
df <- data.frame(data)

graph_parameter_product <- function(data_set, column_value, bin_width, title_value) {
  graph <- ggplot(data_set, aes(x= column_value )) +
    geom_histogram(binwidth = bin_width, fill= "lightblue", colour= "black", aes(y=after_stat(density))) + 
    xlab("Measurement") +
    ylab("Density") +
    labs(title = title_value ) +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
    stat_function(fun = dnorm,
                  args = list(mean = mean(column_value), sd = sd(column_value)),
                  mapping=aes(colour = "Normal")) +
    stat_function(fun = dlnorm,
                  args = list(meanlog = mean(log(column_value)), sdlog = sd(log(column_value))),
                  linetype="dotted", linewidth=1.2, mapping = aes(colour = "LogNormal")) +
    scale_colour_manual(values = c("red", "black")) + 
    labs(colour="Distribution")
  
  graph 
}

graph_parameter_product(df, data, 5, "Test Data")
```

[image]

Also, I changed `..density..` to `after_stat(density)` which is the new way of doing that and same for `size=1.2` to `linewidth=1.2`,

As for getting the `dnorm()` and `dlnorm()` functions on the scale of the counts, you can multiply the density by n*bin_width.  I made two functions `dnormc()` and `dlnormc()` that do this and take the relevant inputs.  You can see below the result is the same, but the scale on y is frequency instead of density.

```r
dnormc <- function(bin_width, n, ...){
  (n*bin_width)*dnorm(...)
}
dlnormc <- function(bin_width, n, ...){
  (n*bin_width)*dlnorm(...)
}

graph_parameter_product_c <- function(data_set, column_value, bin_width, title_value) {
  graph <- ggplot(data_set, aes(x= column_value )) +
    geom_histogram(binwidth = bin_width, fill= "lightblue", colour= "black") + 
    xlab("Measurement") +
    ylab("Frequency") +
    labs(title = title_value ) +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
    stat_function(fun = dnormc,
                  args = list(mean = mean(column_value), 
                              sd = sd(column_value), 
                              bin_width=bin_width, 
                              n=nrow(df)),
                  mapping=aes(colour = "Normal")) +
    stat_function(fun = dlnormc,
                  args = list(meanlog = mean(log(column_value)), 
                              sdlog = sd(log(column_value)),
                              bin_width=bin_width, 
                              n=nrow(df)),
                  linetype="dotted", linewidth=1.2, mapping = aes(colour = "LogNormal")) +
    scale_colour_manual(values = c("red", "black")) + 
    labs(colour="Distribution")
  
  graph 
}

graph_parameter_product_c(df, data, 5, "Test Data")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-08-02 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>